# Почему stdafx.h нужно включать первым?

Tags: c++

Почему `<stdafx.h>` нужно включать первым?

Answer (score 1):

`stdafx.h` должен идти первым только в том случае, если для транслируемого модуля включены *предварительно скомпилированные заголовки*(precompiled headers); если не они не включены, то никаких ограничений нет.

Почему вообще ограничение существует? Потому что Visual Studio вместо `#include "stdafx.h"` «вставляет» содержимое PCH файла и, соответственно, всё, что предшествует этой строке, считается частью PCH файла. Поэтому нельзя ничего вставлять до включения `stdafx.h`

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю для прочтения свою статью: [StdAfx.h](http://www.viva64.com/ru/b/0265/). В ней дан ответ на этот и другие вопросы, связанные с Precompiled Headers. Если её прочитать, больше не будет непонимания, как же это всё работает. :)